# Output python query output into string

Tags: mysql-python, gae-python27

Trying to use this syntax:

```
import MySQLdb as mdb
con = mdb.connect(host = 'host', user = 'user', passwd = 'pwd', db = 'db');
cur = con.cursor()
cur.execute('select distinct name from names');
rows = cur.fetchall()
print(rows)
(('1',), ('2',), ('3',), ('4',), ('5',))
```

I need to get this output to be in the format of a string so that I can include it as a variable in another query I'll be running in the same script.

```
'1','2','3','4','5'
```

I'm running this from command line and have tried a few things:

```
>>> for row in rows:
...   print "%s," % row
...
```

but unfortunately doesn't give me what I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
rows = ('1',), ('2',), ('3',), ('4',), ('5',)
output1=output2=""

for row in rows:
    output1 += '\'' + str(row[0][0]) + '\'' + ','
    output2 += ' ' + str(row[0][0]) + ' ' + ','

# To delete last char: ','
output1 = output1[:-1]
output2 = output2[:-1]

print(rows)          # (('1',), ('2',), ('3',), ('4',), ('5',))
print(output1)       # '1','2','3','4','5'
print(output2)       #  1 , 2 , 3 , 4 , 5
```

output1 is what you expect, but you should probably feed output2 string to your script.